forward from ElasticLoadBalancingV2 to ElasticLoadBalancing
What is the correct way to forward from a ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer to a ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer?
From what I have read using TargetType: alb will not work because it requires V2.
